# What happens when you increase temperature AND flow to a temperature compensated flow sensor?

Tags: sensor

OK, so I basically have a WARM AIR valve to control temperature and COLD AIR valve that controls flow. The warm air valve is going to gradually be opened, and I want to know what kind of effects it will have on my temperature compensated air flow sensor (uses current through a heated element to measure flow). Since opening the warm air valve will increase temperature AND flow to the temperature compensating sensor, I have 3 logical conclusions to what will happen with the COLD AIR valve.

1. The increase in temperature takes priority and will cause an increase in heat to the heated element (biasing it towards sensing a low flow condition), causing an increase in resistance and resultant decrease in current which commands the flow valve to open wider to send more COLD AIR flow downstream.
2. The increase in flow takes priority and will cause an decrease in heat to the heated element (biasing it towards sensing a high flow condition), causing a decrease in resistance and resultant increase in current which commands the flow valve to close down to send less COLD AIR flow downstream.
3. Neither parameter takes priority. The increase in flow causing a cooling effect on the heated element is counteracted by the increased temperature of the air, and the flow sensor is none the wiser.

Has anyone who has worked with temperature compensated air flow sensors help me understand which response is the most likely? NOTE: I've already confirmed that increasing COLD AIR flow to the sensor sends a command to close down the COLD AIR valve.

Comment: Do you have a data sheet for the sensor? Most hot wire sensors also have a temperature sensing element. That is taken into account for the flow calculation.

Comment: The velocity of air cannot be differentiated from the random velocity motions of molecules in heated air. A single sensor cannot separate these two effects. It's not possible. (Think about how a sensor measures temperature -- and read Boltzmann's work, if necessary.) This has a significant impact in measuring the exhaust temperature, for example, of a car exhaust system. You have to compensate your measurement to take into account the air density and its velocity across a sensor. No way around it.

Comment: Let’s say, for the sake of the argument, that the temperature sensor is reading that the temperature is too low regardless of how hot the air gets.

Comment: @j0hnnyb0y Apply a butane torch. If it still reads too low, chances are your sensor has a problem or else your circuit connected to it has a problem or else the software being used has a problem. Regardless, I have far too few details to offer a useful opinion about your setup.